# Community Builder Login Page not working in Napili Template

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, napili, login

I am setting up a login page for a community using the Customer Service (Napili) Summer '17 template.

I used the Login template from the builder to customize the template and also set up under Administration -> Login & Registration the login page to the login community builder page.

The problem is that /login still redirects to the default login page and /s/login redirects to the custom Login template. Is there a possibility to set the custom login page to the /login url or just to disable the default login page?

Comment: Is the community published (activated) yet or unpublished?

Comment: Community is set to active and the pages are published.